# Не могу перетащить Physic Material на коллайдер

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть у меня GameObject это простой круг который отскакивает от стенок.
Но при отскоке он теряет энергию и останавливается хотя не должен.
Вот код отскока

```csarp
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        Rigidbody2D collidingRB = collision.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        collidingRB.velocity = Vector3.Reflect(collision.transform.position, -collision.contacts[0].normal);
       
        GameObject collidedObject = collision.gameObject;

        // Получаем компонент Transform объекта (отвечает за его положение и масштаб)
        Transform collidedTransform = collidedObject.transform;

        // Увеличиваем масштаб объекта на 10%
        collidedTransform.localScale *= scaleMultiplier;
 
     
    }
```

Прочитал что нужно установить Physic Material на коллайдеры. Но я не могу этого сделать.
Я его создал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь перетащить в коллайдер в поле Material но там появляется кружек запрета, мол не могу.
Почему так?
Как пофиксить и сделать что бы мой шарик не терял скорости при столкновении со стенами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен 2D Physic Material
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html

У вас на скриншоте Physic Material для 3D физики.